# Linking entities with repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I am fairly new to repository pattern, I have the following project structure -

> DAL -> Core -> Web

I can get ***ASP.NET MVC*** listing all customers and users individually, however I need a list of Customers assigned to each user (Customers.PrimaryUser) on the User model.

How do I get the relations from Entity Framework to show in the Models?

**DAL**

Contains Entity Framework Model

UserService.cs

```
public class UserService : ServiceBase<IUserModel>, IUserService
{
    public UserService()
        : this(new UserRepository())
    {
    }

    private IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository ?? new UserRepository();
    }

    protected override Type LogPrefix
    {
        get { return this.GetType(); }
    }

    public UserListViewModel GetUserList(int PageSize, int CurrentPage)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((CurrentPage == 0) || (PageSize == 0))
                return null;

            IQueryable<User> query = _userRepository.GetQueryable();

            UserListViewModel model = new UserListViewModel();

            if (model.TotalPageCount != 1)
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Surname).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);

            model.UserList = new List<UserModel>();
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID));
            model.UserList = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(query.ToList(), model.UserList);

            return model;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            this.LogError("Error getting the user list", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public UserModel GetSingle(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(UserModel entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(UserModel entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(UserModel entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<UserModel> GetAll(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<UserModel> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<UserModel> Query(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public long Count(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public long Count()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

UserModel.cs

```
public class UserModel : IUserModel
{
    private ICustomerService _customerService;

    public UserModel()
        : this(new CustomerService())
    {

    }

    public UserModel(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Employee Number")]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    public string SurnameFirstName
    {
        get { return Surname + ", " + Firstname; }
    }
}
```

CustomerModel.cs

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int CustomerType { get; set; }
    public int RefSource { get; set; }
    public DateTime RefDate { get; set; }
    public string RefPerson { get; set; }
    public int RefType { get; set; }
    public string RefNotes { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int LastUpdateBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thats a lot of code..could you narrow it down to the specific part you are having issues with

Comment: This has been edited - now showing the user service and the user/customer models. The relationship should be One User has many customers (Customer.PrimaryUser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make customer list a child of user:**

then you can pull / map the list within your customer service.

**Start by adding CustomerList to you user ViewModel:**

public class UserModel : IUserModel
{
    private ICustomerService _customerService;

```
public UserModel()
    : this(new CustomerService())
{

}

public UserModel(ICustomerService customerService)
{
    _customerService = customerService;
}

public int ID { get; set; }
....
public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> CustomerList { get; set; }
```

**And then in your UserService add the Customer Repo as well as User Repo**

```
private IUserRepository _userRepository;
private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository ?? new UserRepository();
    _customerRepository = _customerRepository ?? new CustomerRepository();
}
```

**and finally, after you pull in your users, use the customerRepo**

```
        model.UserList = new List<UserModel>();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID));
        model.UserList = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(query.ToList(), model.UserList);


        foreach ( var user in model.UserList )
        {
           var custList = _customerRepository.GetCustomersForUser(user.ID).ToList();
           user.CustomerList  = AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<custList, IEnumerable<CustomerModel>>();             
        }

        return model;
```

**Implementing GetCustomersForUser(userID)**

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomersForUser(int userID)
{
   return custCntxt.Customers.Where(c=>c.PrimaryUser == userID);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the way forward, however I am struggling to implement the _customerRepository.GetCustomersForUser(user.ID) method. Could you provide an example for this?

Comment: @MattBaughan, implementing a repo action is a challenge b/c u haven't revealed much about your repo, but my guess is it would look like my updated answer. It's a guideline...

Comment: Perfect, one last issue I can see is the variable custList in the GetUserList method has the following error - 'Cannot resolve symbol custList'.

Comment: @MattBaughan, I think the linq query should return a `tolist()`... ill update... this is because the var anonymous needs a concrete type to work against.

Comment: @MattBaughan, I added the tolist in wrong area. it should not be within the called function, but inside the caller... That way the var understand to get a list back...

Comment: Have moved it to the caller but it has not resolved the issue. It just does not recognize that custList is even declared?

Comment: @MattBaughan, try returning an IEnumberable instead of queryable, or even a List as a last resort...

Comment: No success using both suggestions. When the custlist is declared outside the foreach, Intellisense detects it when doing custlist = _customerRepository.GetCustomersForUser() but not when adding it on to the AUtomatter?

Comment: Resolved. Had to do - AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>(); Then, user.CustomerList = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(custlist, user.CustomerList);